# Using collections and crashing Mac 2016 Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a VBA script to automate deleting rows of different datasets in Excel based on whether a cell in a certain column matches a predefined list of strings (names of manufacturers).  The number of datasets can differ each time and the columns to check will be different in each dataset.  There is a settings page where the user defines the worksheets that include the datasets, the first cell in the column to check in each dataset and also the list of strings to check against and these are all called as defined named ranges.

My Macro seems to work but eventually crashes Excel.  I haven't done any VBA programming for 5 years or so. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Private Sub RemoveManufacturers()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim source As New Collection
Dim manufacturer As New Collection
Dim manufacturer_col As New Collection
Dim key As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim flg As Boolean


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("settings").Activate

'Add Manufacturer Names to Collection

For Each key In Range("manufacturers").Cells
   manufacturer.Add key.Value
Next

'Add Manufacturer Column Refs to manufacturer_col Collection

For Each key In Range("manufacturer_cols").Cells
    manufacturer_col.Add key.Value
Next

'Add User Defined sheetnames to source Collection

For Each key In Range("source").Cells
    source.Add key.Value       
Next

'Define number of iterations based on raw datasets
i = source.Count

'Loop through Raw Data Sheets
Do Until i = 0

    'Add use sheet names to navigate to relevant worksheets
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(source(i)).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Select column with data in
        Range(manufacturer_col(i)).Select

        'Loop through column until a blank cell is found
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            'Define number of iterations based on no. of manufacturers
            j = manufacturer.Count
            flg = False

            'Loop through each Manufacturer name
            Do Until j = 0
               'If match found set Flag to True

               If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, UCase(manufacturer(j))) <> 0 Then
                    flg = True
                    'Get out of loop
                    GoTo IgnoreOrDelete
               End If
               'increment counter
               j = j - 1
            Loop
IgnoreOrDelete:
            'If Flag has been set
           If flg = True Then
               ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=1).Activate
           Else
               ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
           End If
       Loop

    i = i - 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: If I turn on screen updating I can see that it crashes during the loop.... however, it does work successfully for a large number of iterations before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add a key.Value to the collection that already exists, it will crash.

I suspect this has a high probability to be your issue. But I cannot know for sure based on your code alone.

If you're fine with the collection only containing one instance of each unique item, you can just add 'On Error Resume Next' as below:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

If you're not fine with this error, and want to handle it in some other way, please do something like the following:

```
'Add Manufacturer Names to Collection
On Error Goto NameDup:
For Each key In Range("manufacturers").Cells
   manufacturer.Add key.Value
Next
if false then
NameDup:
    'Your code here
end if

'Add Manufacturer Column Refs to manufacturer_col Collection
On Error Goto ColDup:
For Each key In Range("manufacturer_cols").Cells
    manufacturer_col.Add key.Value
Next
if false then
ColDup:
    'Your code here
end if

'Add User Defined sheetnames to source Collection
On Error Goto SourceDup:
For Each key In Range("source").Cells
    source.Add key.Value       
Next
if false then
SourceDup:
    'Your code here
end i

'Reset error handler
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: All Values entered into the Collections are unique - I've commented on the question to explain where it crashes.